# emacs org-bullets not supported

Tags: kubuntu, emacs, encoding, utf-8, org-mode

I'm using ubuntu 19.04 with KDE5
org-bullets doesn't seem to work for me on both terminal mode as well as GUI mode. I tried it on a windows VM, it works fine there, but not in my linux machine.
My locale is using utf-8.
[image]

```lisp
  (use-package org-bullets
    :hook (org-mode . org-bullets-mode)
    :config
    (setq org-bullets-bullet-list '("◉" "⁑" "⁂" "❖" "✮" "✱" "✸")))
```

`M-x RET describe-current-coding` output

```
  U -- utf-8-dos (alias: mule-utf-8-dos cp65001-dos)

Default coding system (for new files):
  U -- utf-8 (alias: mule-utf-8 cp65001)

Coding system for keyboard input:
  U -- utf-8-unix (alias: mule-utf-8-unix cp65001-unix)

Coding system for terminal output:
  U -- utf-8 (alias: mule-utf-8 cp65001)

Coding system for inter-client cut and paste:
  nil
Defaults for subprocess I/O:
  decoding: U -- utf-8-unix (alias: mule-utf-8-unix cp65001-unix)

  encoding: U -- utf-8-unix (alias: mule-utf-8-unix cp65001-unix)


Priority order for recognizing coding systems when reading files:
  1. utf-8 (alias: mule-utf-8 cp65001)
  2. iso-2022-7bit 
  3. iso-latin-1 (alias: iso-8859-1 latin-1)
  4. iso-2022-7bit-lock (alias: iso-2022-int-1)
  5. iso-2022-8bit-ss2 
  6. emacs-mule 
  7. raw-text 
  8. iso-2022-jp (alias: junet)
  9. in-is13194-devanagari (alias: devanagari)
  10. chinese-iso-8bit (alias: cn-gb-2312 euc-china euc-cn cn-gb gb2312)
  11. utf-8-auto 
  12. utf-8-with-signature 
  13. utf-16 
  14. utf-16be-with-signature (alias: utf-16-be)
  15. utf-16le-with-signature (alias: utf-16-le)
  16. utf-16be 
  17. utf-16le 
  18. japanese-shift-jis (alias: shift_jis sjis)
  19. chinese-big5 (alias: big5 cn-big5 cp950)
  20. undecided 

  Other coding systems cannot be distinguished automatically
  from these, and therefore cannot be recognized automatically
  with the present coding system priorities.

Particular coding systems specified for certain file names:

  OPERATION TARGET PATTERN      CODING SYSTEM(s)
  --------- --------------      ----------------
  File I/O      "\\.tzst\\'"            (no-conversion . no-conversion)
                "\\.zst\\'"             (no-conversion . no-conversion)
                "\\.dz\\'"              (no-conversion . no-conversion)
                "\\.txz\\'"             (no-conversion . no-conversion)
                "\\.xz\\'"              (no-conversion . no-conversion)
                "\\.lzma\\'"            (no-conversion . no-conversion)
                "\\.lz\\'"              (no-conversion . no-conversion)
                "\\.g?z\\'"             (no-conversion . no-conversion)
                "\\.\\(?:tgz\\|svgz\\|sifz\\)\\'"
                                        (no-conversion . no-conversion)
                "\\.tbz2?\\'"           (no-conversion . no-conversion)
                "\\.bz2\\'"             (no-conversion . no-conversion)
                "\\.Z\\'"               (no-conversion . no-conversion)
                "\\.elc\\'"             utf-8-emacs
                "\\.el\\'"              prefer-utf-8
                "\\.utf\\(-8\\)?\\'"    utf-8
                "\\.xml\\'"             xml-find-file-coding-system
                "\\(\\`\\|/\\)loaddefs.el\\'"
                                        (raw-text . raw-text-unix)
                "\\.tar\\'"             (no-conversion . no-conversion)
                "\\.po[tx]?\\'\\|\\.po\\."
                                        po-find-file-coding-system
                "\\.\\(tex\\|ltx\\|dtx\\|drv\\)\\'"
                                        latexenc-find-file-coding-system
                ""                      (undecided)
  Process I/O   nothing specified
  Network I/O   nothing specified
```

Comment: Does putting `LANG=en_IN.utf8` or whatever is appropriate in your `.bashrc` help?

Comment: Nope! tried putting that in `.bashrc` , `/etc/default/locale`, nothing worked